# Simple autologin script does not work

Tags: internet-explorer, autoit

Here is my simple autoit autologin script on public webpage.

```html
#include <IE.au3>

Global $oIE = _IECreate("http://www.zoznam.sk/",1)

$username = _IEGetObjByName($oIE, "login")
$password = _IEGetObjByName($oIE, "password")
$oForm = _IEGetObjByName ($oIE, "prihlas")



_IEFormElementSetValue ($username, "123456")
_IEFormElementSetValue ($password, "654321")

Sleep(1000)
_IEAction($oForm, "click")
```

It writes username and password but does not click the button.
Can something block that action ? some IE settings ? or ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this at work. Different approach :-) If I try that code, it shows "Nesprávne zadané prihlasovacie údaje" which translated by google means "wrong login data".

```
#include <IE.au3>
$sUsername = "Username"
$sPassword = "Password"
$sUrl = "http://www.zoznam.sk"
;~ $oIE = _IECreate($sUrl, 0, 1, 0, 1)
$oIE = _IECreate($sUrl, 1);, 1, 0, 1)
;~ Sleep(2000)
$oHWND = _IEPropertyGet($oIE, "hwnd")
WinSetState($oHWND, "", @SW_MAXIMIZE)
$oForm = _IEFormGetCollection($oIE, 2)
$oUsername = _IEGetObjById($oForm, "loginid")
$oPassword = _IEGetObjById($oForm, "passwordid")
_IEFormElementSetValue($oUsername, $sUsername)
_IEFormElementSetValue($oPassword, $sPassword)
;~ _IEFormSubmit($oForm)
Local $oSubmit = _IEGetObjByName($oIE, "prihlas")
_IEAction($oSubmit, "click")
```

Comment: Thanks :) I ll try it Monday in work and then ill inform you if it works or not.

Comment: So i tested it and its not wotking in work, so I made simple mouseclick script and it works fine, guess thats the only way i can solve this. But thank for helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
#include <IE.au3>
$sUsername = "Username"
$sPassword = "Password"
$sUrl = "http://www.zoznam.sk"
;~ $oIE = _IECreate($sUrl, 0, 1, 0, 1)
$oIE = _IECreate($sUrl, 1);, 1, 0, 1)
;~ Sleep(2000)
$oHWND = _IEPropertyGet($oIE, "hwnd")
WinSetState($oHWND, "", @SW_MAXIMIZE)
$oForm = _IEFormGetCollection($oIE, 2)
$oUsername = _IEGetObjById($oForm, "loginid")
$oPassword = _IEGetObjById($oForm, "passwordid")
_IEFormElementSetValue($oUsername, $sUsername)
_IEFormElementSetValue($oPassword, $sPassword)
_IEFormSubmit($oForm)
```

Comment: Thank you, your script work perfect, I just find out that it works without problem on my Home PC but its not working on my Working PC.There must be som resctriction in Company where I work so thats why my Script does not work too. But thanks for help one more time ! :)

Comment: No problem. What problem occurs at work? Maybe you need proxy credentials.

Comment: For example if I use your script it will only open IE with that website, then insert username and password and then it ends, I find out that some IE commands in my work are running and some are like forbiden or what.     _IEFormElementSetValue is wroking every time, but _IE action commands like "click" are not or like in this script _IEFormSubmit($oForm)